# How to use jolt to parse array of array

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I want to use jolt to parse the json. But I can't get the age value in the first level successfully. May someone help me?
The input json is like this:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "age": "20",
  "Photos": [
    {
      "a": "AAA.jpg",
      "b": "BBB.jpg",
      "XXX123": [
        {
          "v1": "AAA.jpg",
          "v2": "BBB.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "XXX123": {
            "*": {
              //"*": "&2.[&1].&",
              "@(2,a)": "&2.[&1].a",
              "@(2,b)": "&2.[&1].b",
              "@(3,age)": "&3.[&1].age"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The output I want:

```
{
  "XXX123" : [ {
    "a" : "AAA.jpg",
    "b" : "BBB.jpg",
    "age" : "20"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "XXX123": {
            "*": {
              //"*": "&2.[&1].&",
              "@(2,a)": "&2.[&1].a",
              "@(2,b)": "&2.[&1].b",
              "@(4,age)": "&2.[&1].age"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You were close.

```
"@(3,age)": "&3.[&1].age" 
needed
"@(4,age)": "&2.[&1].age"

From where that line was you needed to go up the tree 5 levels.
Counting from Zero

0 -> "*" 
1 -> "XXX123"
2 -> "*"
3 -> "Photos"
4 -> your top level input
then lookup "age" in the top level map
```